# To check/uncheck a checkbox on hitting either enter or spacebar in keyboard?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a checkbox which looks like radio button which is actually a css background image.For this  element i want the user to be able to check or uncheck it using either spacebar or enter key in keyboard.

Inside the span element i tried putting a onkeypress function

Here is my code:

```
<span class=" " role="checkbox" tabindex="0" onKeypress="myFunction(event)"

    function myFucntion(event) {

      var node = event.currentTarget


      var state = node.getAttribute('aria-checked').toLowerCase()

      if (event.type === 'click' || 
          (event.type === 'keydown' && event.keyCode === 32)
          ) {
              if (state === 'true') {
                node.setAttribute('aria-checked', 'false')

              }
              else {
                node.setAttribute('aria-checked', 'true')

              }  

        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
      }

    }
```

I have tried this logic from: https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20160317/examples/checkbox/checkbox-1.html

```
  My question is 1) how do i change the image when the user checks/unchecks it
                   2) how to handle the spacebar/enter keycodes
                   3) how to store image inside a javascript variable
    Apologies for not being able to put the proper code,this is just partial one,but any kind of help would be highly appreciated.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this custom checkbox,works for spacebar but not for enter key.
https://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/BiHzp

```
<form action="#">
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test1" />
    <label for="test1">Red</label>
  </p>
  <p>
</form>
```